# Does move assignment break the references?

Tags: c++, move-assignment-operator

I don't understand if a move assignment is able/free to change the address of a variable x and invalidate all the pointers and references storing &x.
I figure that it's false because a default move assignment move each member and preserve the this pointer but is it guaranteed ?

EDIT : Example

```
int x(1), y(2);
int& ref(x);
x = std::move(y);
// ref still valid ?
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? (E.g. some code that you're not sure if it's correct or not)

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with move-assignment. If you have a reference to an object and then re-assign that object, sure, the reference remains usable but now refers to the changed object. Also note that for `int`s, moving and copying is just the same.

Comment: @5gon12eder Ok. So you confirm that a default (compiler) move assignment is preserving the address ?

Comment: The address of `x`? How could it ever change? It's just an `int` on the stack.

Comment: @5gon12eder yes of course

Comment: Sorry, I think that your question really isn't clear. Can you maybe come up with an example that is more closely related to what actual problem you have in mind? You're not really worried that `int x = 1; int& ref = x; x = 2; std::cout << ref;` could be invalid, are you?

Comment: "change the address of a variable x" - there is no such thing , variables have a fixed address their entire life

Comment: So if i resume, move assignment consist by moving recursively the members of an object until a copy of a fundamental type occurs ?

Comment: `move` doesn't mean "move this thing", it means "move the contents of this thing".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Moving to or from an object does not invalidate references or pointers to the object. The address of both objects remains the same.

Comment: Thank you. Simple and complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

References are just alternate names to existing objects. That is, `x` and `ref` are entirely interchangable (although I'm not sure if `decltype(x)` and `decltype(ref)` are identical): when `x` changes using the other name `ref` will correspondingly see the same change. Likewise, the other way around. The same is true with pointers to objects.

Invalidating references and pointers happens when the referenced entity somehow goes away. For example, when you have a reference to an element in a `std::vector<T>` and the capacity of the vector changes, the reference is invalidated because the underlying object moves away.

Of course, for your example of `int` using `std::move(y)` is rather pointless anyway: the built-in types do not really have any move constructors, i.e., it is equivalent to a copy. However, even when using a class type, object and a reference to it still refer to the same object.